# how to display Images with out uploading.

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to upload an image with out being saved in server and delete the temp files every hour.

Comment: Could you clarify by providing an example of what you want to achieve?

Comment: Would like know the use case? Tryouts before confirmation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

normaly, when a user uploads an image, it's automaticly stored an the server. in temp dir or the direction you've told.
if you don't wan't to have the file on your server, use html5 localStorage.
https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mydeveloperworks/blogs/bobleah/entry/html5_code_example_store_images_using_localstorage57?lang=en

heres another link witch could help you:
[Loading an image to localStorage and setting an image src to that location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11582556/loading-an-image-to-localstorage-and-setting-an-image-src-to-that-location)